# Tsql to get first random product in a category

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I've this result set:

```
select a.id, a.categoria from Articolo a
where novita = 1
order by a.categoria, newid()

id          categoria
----------- -----------
3           4
11          4
1           4
12          5
13          5
4           6
```

and i would to get the first product (in a random order) from each different category:

```
id          categoria
----------- -----------
3           4
12          5
4           6
```

Ideally something like

```
select FIRST(a.id), a.categoria from Articolo a
where novita = 1
order by a.categoria, newid()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Use `MAX(a.id)` with `GROUP BY a.categoria`</strike>

```
SELECT MAX(a.id), a.categoria 
from Articolo a
where novita = 1
GROUP BY a.category
```

---

### Update

To get random id for each `categoria` you can use the [ranking function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY categoria)` with `ORDER BY NEWID` to get a random ordering, like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT id, categoria, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY categoria
                                          ORDER BY NEwID()) AS rn
  FROM Articolo
)
SELECT id, categoria
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

See it in action here:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee96a/4)

This way, it will give you a random id for each `categoria` each time.

---

**However,** If you want the first, you can use the `ORDER BY(SELECT 1)` inside the ranking function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT id, categoria, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY categoria
                                          ORDER BY (select 1)) AS rn
  FROM Articolo
)
SELECT id, categoria
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

- [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee96a/5)

This will give you the first id for each `categoria`.

**Note that:** There is no meaning of the *first* value in the database concepts, because in the relational model, the rows order is not significant. And ***it is not guaranteed*** to return the same order each time, you *have* to `ORDER BY` specific column to get consistent ordering.

Comment: Yes, but max will give to me always the biggest ID, instead i want a random one...